# Disabling laptop monitor on boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution

I'm using a laptop with Ubuntu (no graphical desktop) to do all of my work. The resolution is awful, at 1024x576 or something similar. So I just close my laptop lid and plug it into an external monitor - but the external one never seems to stretch out to its full size.

The reason for this is that the laptop monitor is always enabled - even when the laptop lid is closed. As a result, the external monitor never assumes the full size, and any time I set GRUB to use a resolution higher than 1024x576, the external screen ignores it.

Is there any way to disable the laptop screen in GRUB, or to specify which screen I want as the primary one? I've tried Google, and absolutely nothing comes up.

(The computer is a Lenovo S10e, if it helps at all.)

Comment: Well, in Windows, you could select the primary display **after** you connected the second. I doubt that you can set the external display as default, seeing as it would give a lot of problems to the graphics card (they expect some kind of display).

Comment: @doktoro-reichard Uhh, this is in Linux.

Comment: I know, I'm just telling you my experience (and not answering **because** I don't have Unix). Now, graphics cards **need** to be connected to a display at start - tried to disconnect my VGA cable from the PC then reconnected while the system was running, it froze. What this means is that unless the graphics board is **granted** that there is a display, it won't output anything. And since a laptop already has a display, it will output to there. Besides, you said you weren't using a graphical interface so why (in my opinion) should there be a function to control displays?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - You're totally misinterpreting what I'm asking for. I'm asking for a way to disable my laptop's screen in favour of using my external VGA output. Your comment added nothing to the discussion.

And besides, "why (in my opinion) should there be a function to control displays?" Maybe because some people like myself want to use an external display over the pre-installed laptop display. It's not unheard of.

Comment: @zagrimsan - My question stated that I'm running no graphical desktop, ergo I don't use X. Unless I'm missing something big, why would an X utility solve a non-X problem?

Comment: @Joshua maybe [this](http://systembash.com/content/how-to-turn-off-your-monitor-via-command-line-in-ubuntu/) post might help

Comment: @Joshua - Sorry for missing that part about not having X. In that case things are a bit more difficult as the configuration you want would likely need to be passed as kernel parameters, which requires that the Intel graphics kernel driver would support setting up these things with parameters, and I'm not at all confident that that would be the case.

Comment: Please post the output of `uname -a`

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - While that is a nice post, it still applies to X. **I don't have any form of graphical window system on my machine**, and I don't plan on getting one soon.

Comment: @zagrimsan - I managed to do just that, passing a single line to GRUB on boot to disable my laptop LCD, which let the external VGA display take over and set its own resolution.

Comment: @zagrimsan - I will, give me some time! I'm not able to accept my own answer until two days have passed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to find a fix for my problem.
I simply added this to my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="<default paramaters> video=LVDS-1:d"
```

Then did a good ol' fashin `update-grub`.

This disabled the laptop's LCD on boot, and allowed the external monitor to automatically set its resolution, which worked without a hitch.

Comment: This worked for me. I got the name for my screen by running `xrandr`.

Comment: I had to use `LVDS-1` (with a hyphen) as in the example although `xrandr` gave the name as `LVDS1` (without hyphen).

Answer (score 7):

**If** your kernel has i915 driver enabled, the following (which I quote from ArchLinux Wiki, and which in turn quotes from nouveau wiki) might prove helpful.

Basically you could experiment with adding `video=...` parameter in grub using the `d` option (see the parameter format below) to disable the internal monitor (whichever name it might have for `<conn>` option you need to find from the system log which should display the available options during kernel start-up. The information might still be available from previous start-up in `/var/log/dmesg` if your distro has that, please try `grep i915 /var/log/dmesg*` and post it here.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_Mode_Setting:

> A mode can be forced on the kernel command line. Unfortunately, the
>   command line option video is poorly documented in the DRM case. Bit
>   and pieces on how to use it can be found in
>
> ```
> http://cgit.freedesktop.org/nouveau/linux-2.6/tree/Documentation/fb/modedb.txt
> http://cgit.freedesktop.org/nouveau/linux-2.6/tree/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_fb_helper.c
> ```
>
> The format is:
>
> `video=<conn>:<xres>x<yres>[M][R][-<bpp>][@<refresh>][i][m][eDd]`
>
> ```
> <conn>: Connector, e.g. DVI-I-1, see your kernel log.
> <xres> x <yres>: resolution
> M: compute a CVT mode?
> R: reduced blanking?
> -<bpp>: color depth
> @<refresh>: refresh rate
> i: interlaced (non-CVT mode)
> m: margins?
> e: output forced to on
> d: output forced to off
> D: digital output forced to on (e.g. DVI-I connector)
> ```
>
> You can override the modes of several outputs using "video" several
>   times, for instance, to force DVI to 1024x768 at 85 Hz and TV-out off:
>
> `video=DVI-I-1:1024x768@85 video=TV-1:d`

Comment: Thanks for this! While I managed to fix the problem using that very method, I didn't know of all the possible options. I might need these in the future! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The comment I left lead me to [search Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+monitor+on+ubuntu) and, as you said, the problem didn't seem all that uncommon, as I got a lot of results (so maybe you were just a little too lazy :) )

Nonetheless, [this](http://danielj.se/2011/04/22/ubuntu-shell-script-to-enable-and-disable-secondary-monitor/) link shows a bash script that might do the trick.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Turn on: 1\nTurn off: 2"
read option
if [ $option = 1 ];
then xrandr --output DFP2 --auto --left-of DFP1
elif [ $option = 2 ];
then xrandr --output DFP2 --off
fi
```

As a comment in the link said, `DFP1` and `DFP2` may change according to your system, so first query `xrandr`as it will give you the names of the displays you currently have. Then adapt the script as needed.

I assume you can run this at startup, so, like I said, adapt as needed.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution shell script

```sh
dmesg | grep "\[.*\] usb [^:]*: .*$input" | grep -o -P "usb .*?:" | grep -o "[0-9][^:]*" | uniq | while read device; do echo enabled >/sys/bus/usb/devices/$device/power/wakeup; done
```

`$input` = The name of your device. accepts regex and can be only part of the name of the device.

---

Here is how it gets the ids of the device:
`input="HyperX"`

- `dmesg | grep "\[.*\] usb [^:]*: .*$input"`

```
[    2.117325] usb 1-2.1.3: Product: HyperX Alloy Elite
[    2.117326] usb 1-2.1.3: Manufacturer: HyperX Alloy Elite
```

- `dmesg | grep "\[.*\] usb [^:]*: .*HyperX" | grep -o -P "usb .*?:"`

```
usb 1-2.1.3:
usb 1-2.1.3:
```

- `dmesg | grep "\[.*\] usb [^:]*: .*HyperX" | grep -o -P "usb .*?:" | grep -o "[0-9][^:]*" | uniq`

```
1-2.1.3
```

---

gist = https://gist.github.com/FlafyDev/925cb58aaa3e16dad8483e8702e257af

Answer (score -2):

Im sure someone can give a Linux related answer that would solve your problem.  But in the mean time you can disconnect the ribbon cable from the display to the motherboard of the laptop.  If you are comfortable opening up your laptop, it should be fairly easy to do - and redo.

Comment: That sounds good, but I also take the laptop out with me every day. Disconnecting the ribbon cable when I leave home then reconnecting it when I get home is totally impractical. Thanks for the answer anyways! :)

Comment: This didn't work for me. I removed the whole screen from the laptop, but still X would try to display on the missing laptop screen.